# Юнит тестирование асинхронного метода

Tags: c#, asp.net, юнит-тесты

Написал метод для тестирования входа в аккаунт:

```
    [Fact]
    public void LoginIsSuccessful()
    {           
        var result = controller.Login(new LoginViewModel()
        {
            Login = "12345il",
            Password = "12345678"
        }).Result;
        ....
    }
```

При его запуске возникает ошибка:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Переменная result принимает значение null в процессе теста. Стал выяснять почему. Оказалось, всё из-за вызова метода аутентификации:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ServiceResult result = await _accServ.LoginAsync(model);
            if (result.Successful)
            {
                // без вызова этого метода, тест проходит без ошибок
                await AuthenticateAsync(model.Login);
                // в нём всего лишь устанавливаются куки
                ...
            }
           ....
    }
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: `public void LoginIsSuccessful()` сделать таким `public async Task LoginIsSuccessful()` результат получать так `var result = await controller.Login(new ….)`

Comment: @Bulson точно, спасибо!

Comment: @Bulson достойно ответа :)

Comment: Где у вас происходит инициализация controller?

Comment: @B.Vandyshev в конструкторе класса:
controller = new AccountController(new AccountService(context));